# В цитате (Эдвард Гиббон?) не пропущена ли запятая (см.)?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

[В 408 г., после отстранения от власти и убийства всемогущего временщика Стилихона, пришедшая к власти придворная группировка разорвала союзные отношения с Аларихом и его дружины вновь двинулись на Италию.](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/polk-18/25.htm)

Ещё один *[источник](https://texts.news/drevnego-mira-istoriya/raspad-gibel-zapadnorimskoy-64901.html)*, на сей раз подписанный "Кузищин В.И. ИСТОРИЯ ДРЕВНЕГО РИМА. 2005"... О_о В книжке не этим именем цитата подписана, дважды О_о 8-(

**ВОПРОС:** нужна ли запятая перед "и его дружины"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Запятая не нужна,** указание даты является общим элементом для двух предложений.

Это основной фактор:  события могли быть разделены во времени, но  они относились **именно к 408 году.**

Answer (score 0):

Нет, запятая действительно не требуется. Здесь главную роль играет сочетание "В четыреста восьмом году", являющееся как бы обобщающим для обоих грамматических конструкций. Акцент делается на том, что оба события произошли в один и тот же год (хотя, следует отметить, есть ещё связь между самими конструкциями), что в некоторой степени можно сравнить с двумя придаточными предложениями, относящимися к одному главному и соединенными союзом "и".